# Ошибка при установке гемов

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, ssl, openssl, gems

```
gem install rubocop
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubocop' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
```

Пожалуйста, помогите как это сделать?

> You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store

Comment: А у тебя все-все обновления на убунту стоят? А какая версия убунты? А время на компе - ок?

Comment: @donRumata Да, Ubuntu 20, время в порядке.

Comment: https://github.com/rubinius/docker/issues/5#issuecomment-372355880 не оно?

Comment: @donRumata что такое rbx? У меня нет такого пакета

Comment: Откуда я знаю? Ты же рубидев. Убунта говорит, что `rbx` принадлежит пакету `ruby-build`.